# ML list typing when converting char list to int list

Tags: types, functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I've been having an issue with converting a character list to an int list. My goal is to basically take a number such as 325 and have it return a list of [3,2,5]. What I've done so far is take the number and then convert it to a string, which then gets exploded to a char array. I then want to convert each char to a respective int. When I map my char list into fn c => Char.ord(c) the char list becomes an ?.int list, which prevents me from doing operations(+,-) on it. I'm new to ML and don't have a strong grasp of its type system but it seems odd to me.

Here's the code:

```
open IntInf;

fun fact_helper (0, r : int) = r
  | fact_helper (n : int, r : int) = fact_helper (n-1, n*r);

fun factorial n:int = fact_helper (n, 1);

fun num_to_digits n =  
    let val digits_as_chars = explode (IntInf.toString n);
    in map (fn c => (Char.ord c)) digits_as_chars
    end;
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do `fn c => (Char.ord c) - 48` in my mapping function to get the true digit value. I've done something similar before and it worked then but not now and I'm unsure why I'm getting the *?.int list* type. Original problem can be found as [Project Euler problem 20](https://projecteuler.net/problem=20).

Comment: I added some general code feedback to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you did `open IntInf`, so that type `int` and operators `+` and friends now refer to the `IntInf` module. The ordinary `int` type got shadowed by `IntInf.int` and thus is printed as `?.int` (SML/NJ uses the pseudo syntax `?.x` to refer to names from inaccessible scopes). `Char.ord` returns the ordinary `int` type.

So nothing is necessarily wrong with your code, but the `open` can have a confusing effect. You should generally avoid using `open` in the toplevel scope.

If you really want your `num_to_digits` function to compute with infinite integers then you'll have to wrap a call to `IntInf.fromInt` (or just `fromInt`, since `IntInf` is opened) around `Char.ord c`.

Answer (score 2):

First some feedback on your code:

- The inner parenthesis in `(fn c => (Char.ord c))` is not necessary.
- Since `Char.ord` is equivalent to `fn c => Char.ord c`, you could write `map ord chars`.
- `fun factorial n:int = ...` does not mean what you think it means. The `:int` part here refers to `factorial`'s return type, which is incidentally the same as `n`'s type. What you probably meant to say, but wasn't necessary to say because of type inference, was:

  ```
  fun factorial (n : int) : int = ...
  ```
- Generally the type annotations are unnecessary. The code is quite readable as simply:

  ```
  fun fact_helper (0, r) = r
    | fact_helper (n, r) = fact_helper (n-1, n*r);

  fun factorial n = fact_helper (n, 1);
  ```

Next, building on both of Andreas'es and galfisher's recommendations, you probably want to use both IntInf and numeric operators. Also, there's a pretty neat function in IntInf called `divMod` that gives you both the division and the remainder:

```
open IntInf

fun digits n =
    let fun aux n res =
            case divMod (n, 10) of
                 (0, d) => d::res
               | (n', d) => aux n' (d::res)
    in aux n [] end
```

But when will you actually need a list of digits? Most likely you will want to recurse over that list and build something else, e.g. a sum of digits, or whatever. That recursion pattern – visiting every element in a list consecutively – might as well be applied directly to the digits and generalised into a fold:

```
(* f is the operator that we fold with
 * e is the initial accumulated value (temporary result)
 * n is the number on which we fold across
 *)
fun folddigits f e n =
    case divMod (n, 10) of
         (0, d) => f (d, e)
       | (n', d) => folddigits f (f (d, e)) n'
```

With this you can easily make the digits into a list by folding with the `::` operator:

```
fun digits n = folddigits (fn (d, res) => d::res) [] n
```

Or if you realize that the syntax sugar `op::` is exactly the same as `fn (d, res) => d::res)` and by also performing [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) on the parameter `n`:

```
val digits = folddigits op:: []
```

Or a sum of digits (applied recursively until one digit is left):

```
val sum_of_digits = folddigits
    (fn (d, res) => let val res = d + res in
                      if res < 10 then res else 1 + (res mod 10)
                    end) 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a number to a list of it's digits, you can use this recursive formula (the `@` is list appending operator)

```
list(digits(num)) = list(digits(num/10)) @ list(n % 10)
```

This is how the solution in SMLNJ:

```
fun num_to_array 0 = []
|   num_to_array n = num_to_array(n div 10) @ [n mod 10];
```